# MemoryError for postgresql 9.1.9

Tags: python, postgresql, mod-wsgi

Using postgresql9.1.9 in pylons1.0 project with mod_wsgi.

Getting "out of memory error".

Query is of about 1.4 million lines and it crashes on query.all().
The column used for filtering is indexed.
In postgresql.conf, shared_buffers=24MB, max_connections=100.

Can you please suggest the work around?

Comment: `shared_buffers = 24MB` is **extremely** low nowadays. But the more important setting is `work_mem`. What does the execution plan say? Is the error message really from Postgres or from your programming language? Does the Postgres logfile show any errors? Are you aware that there are 4 bugfix releases available for 9.1.x that you didn't apply?

Comment: Thank you. I tried increasing work_mem from 1MB to 5MB and then 10MB. There is no MemoryError now, but it takes 1 minute in both cases. Is it normal, or do you propose a better value?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: The MemoryError occurs in python script (used by Pylons), not in postgresql.

Comment: I would also try to update to 9.1.13 and run few tests. Thank you so much :)

Comment: If the out of memory occurs in Python then you need to reduce the memory consumption *there* (in your program). Reading 1.4 million rows into memory doesn't sound like such a good idea to begin with.

Comment: I changed python code. And now I use .yield_per() instead of .all()
It solves the problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> Query is of about 1.4 million lines and it crashes on query.all().

When you say *it* crashes: Do you mean the `python` client executable, or the PostgreSQL server?

I strongly suspect the crash is in Python. I'd say you're reading all results into memory at once, and they jus tdon't fit.

What you will need to do is progressively read the query results, process them, and discard them from memory. In `psycopg2` you do this by iterating over the `cursor` object, or using `cursor.fetchone()`. Pylons should offer similar methods.

Comment: It was a python memory error. So I changed the python code. It solves the problem. Thank you :)